# Как запретить нескольким странам подключаться либо к порту 7780 либо к айпи?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как запретить нескольким странам подключаться либо к порту 7780 либо к айпи?
У меня есть пример с GEOIP -
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7780 -m geoip --dst-cc RU -j DROP
Но он не работает я спокойно подключаюсь к серверу в игре

Comment: Я с geoip не работал, но банальная логика подсказывает что вместо dst-cc должно быть что-то другое

Comment: У nftables есть что-то похожее: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/GeoIP_matching